# Is there a way to make the wordpress search query, just search for the pages which have a custom template?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to make the wordpress search just display the pages which have the custom template that called "video-information.php".

In the head of the video-information.php file I added this to create a name to the template

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Video Information
 *
 * @package skytube
 * @since skytube v1.0.0
 */
get_header();
?>
```

I know that wordpress search for the content and everything in the site but I want to limit the query to make it just looking after the pages which have a custom template.

I made some searches and found tutorials but all them talk just about how to limit the search query to the posts and pages or a custom post type.
This is an example of those tutorials.

```
// In function.php file
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('post','page'));
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

The above code can just limit the search query to pages and posts not for specific page which have a custom template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use meta_query and make something like this:

```
function search_custom_template($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set('meta_query', [['key' => '_wp_page_template', 'value' => 'template-custom.php']]);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Check out the official docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Thank you for the hepl but the code dosen't work. Can you test it before? I have worked with Wordpress Query for a long time but I haven't been in a place where I have to work with page template in the query that's why I had to ask you here :)

Comment: I've test it and it works. You've just to replace template-custom.php with your template page. It limits the search only to pages that have the template you specify in the meta_query.